# Cobertura not showing coverage for inherited class

Tags: java, maven, maven-cobertura-plugin

I am facing one issue with cobertura coverage in generated report.

> mvn cobertura:cobertura

I have a class like

> ```
> public class ChildClass extends
>          ReqBuilder<ReqTo, ContextStatic, ContextDynamic>
> ```

This line I am not able to cover.
Why we need to cover for class declaration is what my question is.Because of this it is effecting branch coverage.
Any help would be appreciated.

I have configured maven with cobertura

Thanks
Pradeep

Comment: are you able to find the solution ??

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is a bug in Cobertura on this. But there is a workaround to solve this issue. You need to write a Test class for ReqBuilder.

Please refer : https://sourceforge.net/p/cobertura/bugs/92/